# How to identify each fxml(node) when scene consist of copies of this fxml(node)?

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

A node is a gridPane (1 column width,5 rows height, with labels, buttons with actions) and has a controller. Main controller of application, after button clicked can run FXMLoader and load this gridpane and add into a Hbox (column by column, from the left side, each node with diffrent data).

Problem is, when scene has more than two the same fxml's(nodes), methods from all nodes can change data only in last loaded node. How to separate each node?

It can be solved by inserting another fxml file with controller but when user click 20-40 times it can be problem.

I read the http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial but it didn't help.
Is this a right approach to show diffrent data in the same fxml?

Comment: Just store the controllers in a list.

Comment: And each new controller have to manage this specific fxml?

Comment: Yes there would be one controller instance responsible for the scene created from one fxml.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try this way :)